# Ajax - On success, await for function

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

I have an AJAX function that on success redirects me to another page, and once on that page, it should run another JS function that does some CSS stuff with some elements of that page. But for some reason, the second function does not wait for the page to redirect before running. I've tried `.then` and `async/await`. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is what I've tried:

**JS Functions**

```
async function redirectEvent(event_id) {
  window.location.href = "/event/" + event_id;
}

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

**AJAX Functions I've tried**

```
function inviteEventAttendee(event_id, user_id) {
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
          url: "{{ route('inviteEventAttendee') }}",
          data: { event_id: event_id, user_id: user_id },
          success: async function (response) {
              await redirectEvent(event_id);
              delay(5000).then(() => console.log("Responseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"));
          }
      });
}

function inviteEventAttendee(event_id, user_id) {
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
          url: "{{ route('inviteEventAttendee') }}",
          data: { event_id: event_id, user_id: user_id },
          success: function (response) {
              redirectEvent(event_id).then(() => console.log("Responseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"));
          }
      });
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I run the code, I instantly see the console log and then it redirects that page, so it's not waiting for the page to load.

Comment: "*once on that page, it should run another JS function*" - that'll never work. Unloading the current page will stop all javascript running, when loading the new page only the new javascript will be executed.

Comment: @Bergi is there any way to make the page run a js function when loaded?

Comment: Sure, just put it in the page's `onload` handler. To make that new page only sometimes run the js, you can use an URL parameter or something, but notice that everyone might be able to set this parameter.